# A pendulum is formed by pivoting a long thin rod of length $L$ and mass $m$ about point P on rod which is distance $d$ above the centre

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

How will the Time period be affected as d changes from $\frac{L}{2}$ to zero?

[image: FIGURE]

---

I tried obtaining a relation between time period(T) and d:
assuming the angular oscillations to be small, we can balance the torque about the point P
$I\alpha=mgd.\theta$  and hence, comparing with the general relation of SHM that is, $\alpha=\omega^2\theta$, we can conclude that $\omega=\sqrt\frac{mgd}{I}$  and hence,
$T=2\pi\sqrt\frac{I}{mgd}$
But I'm stuck here and am not able to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: While this is an interesting exercise, it is just that: an exercise in manipulating a formula, not clarifying a physics concept.

Comment: Is the $I$ above about the center of mass or the pivot?

Comment: @JAlex as I took the torque about the pivot point P, I suppose we are supposed to take the $I$ about the pivot itself. So we would use the parallel axis theorem and calculate that

Comment: @PrajwalTiwari, correct you have to be consistent between torque and mmoi summation points. And the summation point has to be either the center of mass, or a fixed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are halfway there!
$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{I}{mgd}}$$
Further, you can write $$I=I_{cm}+Id^2$$
$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{I_{cm}+md^2}{mgd}}$$
Putting $I_{cm}=ml^2/12$
$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l^2/12+d^2}{gd}}$$
That's it! We did it! Now you can proceed! :)

---

Let's just for a minute write $I_{cm}=mk^2$ to take a look at a more general picture.
$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{k^2+d^2}{gd}}$$
$$d^2-\frac{T^2g}{4\pi^2}d+k^2=0$$
The plot of this will look [like](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jxf8uiyqbs). It'll be a good exercise if you interpret it by yourself.

Comment: yes that's what I got after using the parallel axis theorem and now I realise that I should have mentioned that in my approach as well. I can't conclude how the time period would vary while we change the value of d from L/2 to 0. Could you please guide me with that?

Comment: @PrajwalTiwari - plug in the value(s) of $d=0$ and see what comes out, then plug in the value of $d=L/2$ and see what comes out. Then use the algebra rules to see how $T$ behaves when $d$ is increasing. It is helpful to view the result as a dimensionless quantity $$ \frac{T}{2\pi} \sqrt{ \frac{g}{L} } = \sqrt{ \frac{d}{L} + \frac{L^2}{12 d^2} } $$ where $d$ is some proportion of $L$. Better yet, use $x=\frac{d}{L}$ and plot the right hand side.

Comment: @PrajwalTiwari See JAlex comment and the edit on the answer.